# How do you iterate through JSON object in an ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out how to iterate through a JSON object in an ASP.NET MVC controller.  Every example I've come accross looks like the following where the posted JSON is assumed to contain a single object.  However, let's say in my example below I want my controller to handle a collection of people rather than a single person.  My inputModel therefore would contain a bunch of Names and Ages.  For example, `{"Name": "Bob", "Age": "30"},{"Name": "Paul", "Age": "19"}`.  How would you write your controller code to iterate through the people in the inputModel saving each one to that database?

Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(PersonInputModel inputModel) {
try{        
Person person = new Person();
person.Name = inputModel.Name;
person.Age = inputModel.Age;
Add(person);
Save(person);
}
catch {
//handle the error
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well assuming you are sending an array (notice the `[]` brackets around the JSON string because what you have shown in your question is not valid JSON):

```
[{"Name": "Bob", "Age": "30"},{"Name": "Paul", "Age": "19"}]
```

you could take an array:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(PersonInputModel[] persons) 
{
    foreach (var person in persons)
    {
        var name = person.Name;
        var age = person.Age;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```